# Is Sublime Text professional?

Tags: editor

As a student I use Sublime Text for coding with almost every language I am learning: java, php, html... also javascript, css, etc... Do you recommend this editor?

Is it used in the professional environment as well?

Comment: Simply put: yes; that said, this isn't a question for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two extremes to this: in some places, you are told what to use and provided training (ie Visual Studio). In the other extreme you are allowed to use whatever you want. There are very few places that do some combination of both.

As a student, take your time and look at various editors and get a feel for each.

Answer (score 1):

I used sublime text throughout college and now use it at my workplace... 
For an all around quick text editor it works great.. When it comes to programming and tracking data you'll want something like visual studio or eclipse.. Debugging is much better. It just depends on your task at hand.